Transitioning "Back" into single-store mode
Our site is only meant to have 1 single "store"/website. At some point in the distant past, a dev added a second store...and it has lived in the database ever since :( Store 0 (the one I want to keep) and Store 1 (the duplicate that was created and needs to go away!)
It causes problems with the users...because when they update a product attribute, sometimes it targets the wrong store. It's confusing why they have to understand/fiddle with the scope selector when there's only supposed to be 1 store.
We also have some core_config_data targeting store 0, others targeting store 1, and it's never clear which one is being used in a given situation.
I did try just turning Single-Store mode on in the Admin, but it didn't delete any of the duplicate data...it just removed their ability to use the scope selector essentially.
I'm hoping to tackle this problem soon, but am trying to get a rough idea of how hard/how much time it will take/what needs to be done.
Thanks!

By default store_id 0 refers to Admin scope & default values in database. If you have only 1 storeview & it has store_id 1 then you are in a single store installation
